# Правильное употребление многоточия

Tags: пунктуация

В каких ситуациях правильно употреблять многоточие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего многоточие обозначает незавершенность фразы, как бы указывая на ее возможное продолжение. Особенно часто это встречается в прямой речи и выражает неуверенность, неопределенность.
Пример: *"Да, как-то вот так..." - проговорил он.*
Многоточие также может обозначать заминку в речи.
Пример: *"Я... ранен..." - простонал он.* 
Чтобы обозначить многозначительную паузу перед неожиданной информацией.
Пример: *"Что самое примечательное, в високосный год свататься ходили… девушки"*.
Также многоточие может ставиться в цитатах на концах предложений для обозначения того, что текст процитирован не полностью, а также в середине цитаты, чтобы обозначить пропуск - тогда многоточие берется в скобки.
Пример: *"В народе эти високосные (от лат. bis seхtus — «второй шестой»), удлиненные года со времен римлян и греков пользуются дурной славой..."

"Если бы високосный год был каким-то неугодным для церкви (...), то наверняка это отразилось бы в церковных канонах*"